# how to find out that ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is full in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading

How I may know that ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is full? I use

```
e.getActiveCount()>=e.getMaxPoolSize()
```

is it ok if I use it in multithread environment?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `e.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue()` will get you the `BlockingQueue` being used by the underlying `ThreadPoolExecutor`. This is a safe because the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`'s underlying `ThreadPoolExecutor` and that `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `BlockingQueue` are both `final`.

Once you have the `BlockingQueue`, you can can call `remainingCapacity()`, which will return the number of additional elements the queue could hold at the point in time the method is called. This is safe because `BlockingQueue` itself is designed for concurrent use.

Comment: Thank you, but what to do in in my case corepoolsize=maxpoolsize and queue should be always empty? thank you